# Automated push release

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

So I'm using the free version of TFS and I was wondering if there was a way for me to have a link or url on my TFS account that people can go to download my program or is there a way I can have the program when it starts to check and make sure the program is up to date?

Comment: You probably need to package your program using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

Comment: Will that automatically check to make sure the program is up to date when the user launches it?

Comment: Oh, that check... No, it won't. You'd use NuGet mostly with libraries. It allows to version binary dependencies of a project. Sorry, I've misunderstood you. There are couple of ways I've seen people doing this. [a] use a paid service for this - I only know of InstallShield, there are likely to be others. [b] DIY approach where you build a website and post your binaries there. The app pings specific page on your website to get version information and displays a "new version is available" message box. Make an app fully automatic and "self-updatable" is quite a complicated problem.

Comment: There's also ClickOnce, although ClickOnce is fairly awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a number of things. The best out of the box way is to use ClickOnce. This is by far the easyer way. I have a number of them deployed publicly using azure blob storage. For internal use you can use a network or http share that is available thought your company.

If all your users are internal then you can use a self issue cert based on your domain to get full trust.

Without click once you can implement your own checks.

Comment: The program that I'm righting is a Windows form application that access files from an S: (shared) drive. Will using click once with windows azure help me run a check to make sure that the application is up to date? Example I add a new button to the form, the user closes the firm they have open and then reopen and the new button is there. Will this work for that?

Comment: Yes it is. You can comfort a startup check or list start check. There is also an API to let you notify the user on the fly and have them restart to get the new bits.

Comment: I've been looking at click once but for some reason I can't find out how to start it. Is it built in to Visual Studio or another application I need to download?

Comment: It's built into visual studio. Go to the properties for your application project in VS and then to the ClickOnce tab.